# Hyperlink button created via text/css

Tags: html, css

We're working on a website makeover and have the look that we would like but are trying to figure out how to get it to be functional. The page is linked below for reference.

http://centraliowaaccountant.com/newhomepage.html

Basically what we're looking for is the entire area when you hover on "Tax Preparation" to be linked to "tax_preparation.html" instead of just the text if you use an href. Is this something which can be done with just html/css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this css:

```
ul li.tax_prep_menu{padding:0}
ul li.tax_prep_menu a{display:block;padding:15px;}
```

Easy :)

Answer (score 0):

to your li elements apply the following css:

```
padding: 0px;
```

to your a elements apply the following css:

```
padding: 15px;
```

then the full li is clickable, but then the hover background color is messed up, but you can fix that by applying the background color on hover of the li instead of the a element. hope this helps!